# What is the song when Karma was introduced for the first time in episode 2?

Tags: music, assassination-classroom

In the beginning of the 1st episode of season 1, there is a soundtrack playing in the background that gives off sort of calm and mysterious vibe.

Usually, if I encounter an interesting music theme, I am able to find the author of the composition or even the OST itself with enough persistence and searching. However, this one has been a real struggle for me, probably the hardest one to find so far. None of the known methods of identifying music names were crowned with success in the instance with this piece of music, so I really would like to know if anyone knows something about it.

Also, this OST was played at the very end of the 2nd episode of season 1, when Karma was introduced to the audience for the first time.

I have provided a link below to the video of what the soundtrack sounds like:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WX18JNa91-Q

I really would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction because I don't know what else to do to get the answer at this stage.

Comment: The soundtrack albums are http://vgmdb.net/album/50984, http://vgmdb.net/album/58512, http://vgmdb.net/album/58513, and http://vgmdb.net/album/59814. It seems like the piece you're looking for isn't on any of them. (I find this surprising, given that this is one of the more emblematic pieces from the show.)

Answer (score 0):

I find the fact that this particular soundtrack is not listed anywhere quite interesting too. I have scouted various databases along with other forums, but to no avail. If I eventually discover the name of the OST,  I will post it her.